# throw new MongooseError('Mongoose.prototype.connect() no longer accepts a callback');

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nodemon

i got this error in my terminal when i run my index.js file as a 'npx nodemon .\index.js'

this is my 'index.js':

```
const connectToMongo = require('./database');
connectToMongo();
```

this is my dabase.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const mongoURI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/'

const connectToMongo = ()=>{
    mongoose.connect(mongoURI,()=>{
        console.log('connected to mongo')
    })
}

module.exports = connectToMongo;
```

this is my terminal error:

```
  throw new MongooseError('Mongoose.prototype.connect() no longer accepts a callback');
      ^
```

MongooseError: Mongoose.prototype.connect() no longer accepts a callback
at Mongoose.connect (D:\React\inotebook\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:400:11)
at connectToMongo (D:\React\inotebook\backend\database.js:5:14)
at Object. (D:\React\inotebook\backend\index.js:2:1)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
Node.js v18.14.1

i have not so much  idea about nodemon so help me

Answer (score 3):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost:27017"

const connectToMongo = async () => {
try {
    mongoose.set('strictQuery', false)
    mongoose.connect(mongoURI) 
    console.log('Mongo connected')
}
catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
    process.exit()
}
}
module.exports = connectToMongo;
```

this worked for me

Comment: You might not need to add the `process.exit()` line there, as that action (i.e. stopping the entire application) might not necessarily be the action a user might want to take should the connection fail.